# Python script short option filename argument is not recognized as an argument

Tags: python, getopt

I have a script that takes two arguments using sys and getopt module.
The issue I am having is that when using shortopts to test that the arguments are being passed correctly, the short option for the filename argument does not work. Using long option works fine.

Below is the function parsing the arguments from argv:

## FUNCTION

```
    def parseArgs(argv):
    arg_url = ""
    arg_filename = ""
    arg_help = "{0} -u <url> -f <screenshot file name> ".format(argv[0])

    try:
        (opts, args) = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'hu:f', ["help", "url=", "filename="])
    except getopt.GetoptError as err:
        print("\nInvalid command\n")
        print("Help:\n" + arg_help + "\n")
        print("\n" + str(err) + "\n")
        sys.exit(2)

    print("opts print: " + str(opts))

    if len(opts) != 0:
        for (opt, arg) in opts:
            if opt in ("-u", "--url"):
                arg_url = arg
            elif opt in ("-f", "--filename"):
                arg_filename = arg
            else:
                print(arg_help) # print the help message
                sys.exit(2)
    else:
        print(arg_help)
        sys.exit(2)

    print('url:', arg_url)
    print('fileName:', arg_filename)

    return arg_url, arg_filename
```

Below is the terminal output. You can see that the short option for filename doesn't pass a valid value.

## OUTPUT

```
user@562539635f45:/test# python3 imgkit-test.py -u urltest -f test
opts print: [('-u', 'urltest'), ('-f', '')]
url: urltest
fileName:
function output:('urltest', '')
url output: urltest
imageName output:
```

Below is the output for using the long option:

## OUTPUT

```
user@562539635f45:/test# python3 imgkit-test.py -u urltest --filename test
opts print: [('-u', 'urltest'), ('--filename', 'test')]
url: urltest
fileName: test
function output:('urltest', 'test')
url output: urltest
imageName output: test
```

I'm stumped as what could be causing the issue. I'm not seeing anything obvious. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `'hu:f'` - should this be `'hu:f:'` with an extra colon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this was that I was missing an extra colon at **'hu:f'**. Thanks to @slothrop comment.

Correct answer pasted below:

```py
(opts, args) = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'hu:f:', ["help", "url=", "filename="])
```

Documentation reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/getopt.html

> shortopts is the string of option letters that the script wants to
> recognize, with options that require an argument followed by a colon
> (':'; i.e., the same format that Unix getopt() uses).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks @FranciscoMariaCalisto. Answer has been updated.